# How to tell if Chkdsk is frozen?

Tags: chkdsk

I'm running `chkdsk /f /r /x` offline (so I can't see the cmd window, just my Asus boot startup screen with a progress message at the bottom). The message has said "Scanning and repairing drive (C:): 100% complete" for about two days now, but the circle is still spinning so at least the screen itself is not frozen.

I've heard chkdsk can take a long time, even days, and my 500GB HDD almost certainly has problems; I'm running chkdsk because I got a BSOD error "Critical Process Failed" two weeks ago and had to do a system restore. (Also worth noting the message was originally apparently stuck on 12% complete for the better part of a day, but it ultimately jumped to 100%, so I'm not sure if it's still working now).

My main concern, though, is that the HDD Activity light on the front of my laptop is not on, it's not even flashing, so I'm worried chkdsk may have gotten stuck in a loop and I don't know whether I should try to cancel it and boot Windows back up.

This is an Asus Q302LA running Windows 10 Home (pretty sure it's Build 1709, but I don't want to boot it up to check). The HDD came with the computer, which is almost 5 years old.

Comment: check the HDD LED, or open task manager and look at the disk usage

Comment: I'd always weigh patience against time since last backup, for any situation like this. The older your backup, the more patience you require.

Comment: If chkdsk is taking so long that you don't know if it's frozen then it sounds like the wrong tool. Try gnu ddrescue(which is generally a great tool anyway for rescuing data from a problematic hard drive).  Cygwin has a ddrescue  That will always show you progress and won't freeze on a particular percentage.  Also, of course, if chkdsk is struggling so much with a hard drive then I suppose that would indicate the hard drive is not reliable and should be gotten rid of.

Comment: "How to tell if Chkdsk is frozen?" Its been stuck for 2 days...

Comment: @phuclv I mentioned in my post that the HDD LED is not on. Does this mean that Chkdsk is not functioning?

Comment: @ETL, yes, the HDD light should show activity if chkdsk is actually running.  It can take many hours for a large drive with no problems, and longer if there are a lot of problems.  Once you pass about 8 hrs for a moderate size drive (like your 500GB), it's a safe bet that it is hung.  Kill it.  Then run chkdsk (or an alternate program) again.